# Django - Order itertools.chain object by date

Tags: python, django

I get the messages of 2 users Bob and John like this:

```
urlparam = 'John'
own_mx = Message.objects.filter(sender__username=request.user).filter(recipient__username=urlparam)
his_mx = Message.objects.filter(sender__username=urlparam).filter(recipient__username=request.user)
```

then I use itertools' chain function to combine both querysets into one:

```
inbox = chain(own_mx,his_mx)
```

The messages are now grouped by user, but I need them to be ordered by date.

The django model `Message` has a DateTimeField: `sent_at`.

How can I order `inbox` by `sent_at`?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `itertools.chain` returns the `list` instead of queryset you can apply the `sorted` like this.

```
inbox = sorted(chain(own_mx,his_mx), key=attrgetter('sent_at'))
```